# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing if http status code is not 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, meteor, cors

I am using [restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/) plugin to handle my Api Requests.

The issue I am facing is:

If Api returns **200** status code, everything works fine.

But if I send invalid Authentication Bearer Token in header or if any error returns from API, e.g 422, 401, 400 .. etc, my ajax request fails and gives this error:

```
CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
```

Here is my restivus confiqurations:

```
myApi = new Restivus({

    apiPath: 'api/',
    defaultHeaders: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Connection, Content-Language, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept-Language, Accept, Z-Key, Authorization, client-id, client-secret, client_id, client_secret",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    },
    enableCors: true,
    useDefaultAuth: false,
    prettyJson: true,
    defaultOptionsEndpoint: {
        action: function() {
            this.response.writeHead(201, {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Connection, Content-Language, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept-Language, Accept, Z-Key, Authorization, client-id, client-secret, client_id, client_secret",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            });
            this.done();
            return {
                status: "success",
                "data": {
                    "message": "We love OPTIONS"
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: are you setting the headers for the other status codes?

Comment: @nullptr i am not sure about setting headers against specific status codes,  i am setting it in that default section which you can see in my code

Comment: There are a few similar issues mentioned [here](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+cors).  Some of them have workarounds which might be worth a shot.

Comment: @James I already checked that, it doesnt offer any solution for returning CORS headers in case of error status code

Answer (score 1):

I know it's usually standard to not send headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on failed requests (4xx, 5xx). I've worked around this in the past by hosting an API behind a web server like Apache, then instructing the web server to **always** set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, ignoring the status code.

(This is one option. An example of this can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/brianlmoon/2291111c5c69252c85f4?permalink_comment_id=1982454#gistcomment-1982454))

I also went and looked at the [Restivus documentation](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) specifically under the `defaultHeaders` configuration to see if they mention this behavior. Unfortunately, they don't mention this. But they do mention that you can [override the default header behavior](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#response-data) by explicitly providing the headers in your response object.

So you could define a `Response` class similar to this

```
class Response{
    constructor(statusCode, body){
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.body = body;
        this.headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        };
    }
}
```

Then just return a `Response` object anytime you are sending a response, obviously setting `statusCode` and `body` as required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try setting `enableCors` to `false`.

I took a look at the packages code, it's possible when this option is set to true, the package replaces your customised `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` value with the package's default value of `Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept`.

The error message doesn't quite make sense with this reasoning but, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Failing that, are you able to share a complete copy of the request and response headers from your browser's dev tools? I've got a couple other ideas that may help.

Answer (score -2):

hello this is because whenever server return server error status code, the ajax return wont return the response like its return ok (200) status response
you have to catch the request error to handle the error

```
function makeRequest(endpoint, body){  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/' + endpoint,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: body,
        success: function(resp){
            return resp
        }
    }).then((resp)=>{
       //handle success

    }, err =>{
       //handle error

    });    
}
```

Comment: But it say CORS error. Doesnt makes sense

Comment: Can't exactly "handle" the error if cors is blocking you from receiving it.

Comment: hey!, u can only get this cors error "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" when u server has a runtime error or syntax error, its says it works fine with 200 status but got this issue when return another status code.

Comment: better to always be sure of what u are doing before marking answer as not useful d..